# The backslash on last line for multi-line variable definition in Makefile

Tags: makefile, backslash

I have one concern on the last line with backslash if the following line coming without delimiter(whitespace). Is there any other side-effect for this coding style? Specifically, for backslash in the line - $(wildcard $(WORK)/docs/d_*[0-1]_question.txt) **\**

```
DUP_TXT_DEFS := $(WORK)/docs/a.txt          \
                $(wildcard $(WORK)/docs/*_b[0-9].txt) \
                $(wildcard $(WORK)/docs/*_c[0-9].txt) \
                $(wildcard $(WORK)/docs/d_*[0-1]_question.txt) \
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by *following line coming without delimiter(whitespace)*.  It doesn't matter what the content of the next line, whether it starts with whitespace or not: in all cases the next line is appended to the value of the variable.

If you can be 100% sure that the line after that last line you show is blank or has only whitespace or a comment, and contains no "important" content, then there's no problem.

But if someone ever adds any "important" content to the line after that one, it will be a big problem because it will be appended to the variable.  This kind of problem can be tricky to detect just by eyeballing the makefile.  However, usually it can be seen pretty clearly if you carefully examine the error messages generated by make and understand them.

Personally I recommend against doing this.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I agree that the next line will append in any context. If it is an empty line, I try to figure out how Makefile interpret it? In other word, when Make read the empty line(\s + \n), it skips the space(\s), then see return(\n), update the assignment to left-hand side variable. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question, but what happens is that make reads a line, and then checks if the last character is a backslash.  If it is a backslash, then it loops to get the next line as well.  Once it finds a line that doesn't end with backslash, it parses that entire buffer as a single "logical line".  The backslashes and newlines are removed.  There are some other special  handling like condensing whitespace at the end of the line and on the next line, down to one space.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your detailed explanation. It is just like to read the source code. :-)

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR

Remove the backslash from the last line of your multi-line variable definition and you will be fine. Otherwise, the next line will be a part of the definition, which will cause you many more problems.

### Long answer

In this context, `\` means: Ignore the next character. In this case the new-line-character-

The backslash is used here to make the compiler think

```
DUP_TXT_DEFS := $(WORK)/docs/a.txt          \
            $(wildcard $(WORK)/docs/*_b[0-9].txt) \
            $(wildcard $(WORK)/docs/*_c[0-9].txt) \
            $(wildcard $(WORK)/docs/d_*[0-1]_question.txt) \
```

is the same as:

```
DUP_TXT_DEFS := $(WORK)/docs/a.txt $(wildcard $(WORK)/docs/*_b[0-9].txt) $(wildcard $(WORK)/docs/*_c[0-9].txt)$(wildcard $(WORK)/docs/d_*[0-1]_question.txt) (+ the next line)
```

This is great for defining variables like `DUP_TXT_DEFS` with multiple files while keeping readability via multiple lines. The problem here on the last line `$(wildcard $(WORK)/docs/d_*[0-1]_question.txt) \` is that it allows whatever the next non-empty line is to be added as a value to `DUP_TXT_DEFS`. Thereby destroying:

- The variable's value.
- The result of any variable/command/function using the broken variable.
- The compilation of your program.

### Generalised Example

Assuming you have a Makefile like this

```
MY_VAR:= a.txt \
      b.txt \
      c.txt \

move:
  doStuff(MY_VAR)
```

it would be the same as:

```
 MY_VAR:= a.txt b.txt  c.txt move:
```

Fixable by changing `c.txt \` to `c.txt`.

### Should you use the backslash?

In the end it is your call, but personally I would keep using it. Why?

- It improves readability compared to long single-line definitions.
- While easy to make a mistake, it is easily spotable & fixable.

Comment: Thank you for your input and detailed example. It makes me understanding it better. Great!